# Implement Ars Magica magic system into Rolemaster

Tags: game-design, conversion, ars-magica, rolemaster

I was wondering if someone has tried to implement the **Ars Magica** magic system into **Rolemaster**, and how.

I guess you could assign some cost to the *forms* and *techniques*, maybe scaling its values to a 100-based system (multiplying by 5 would be pretty accurate). I'm not sure if the magic realms would be obsolete or just affect some form and/or technique cost. For example, *essence* could be related with *aquam*, *auram*, *ignem* and *terram*, and mentalism obviously with *mentem*.

But what about formulaic spells? Use only a more powerful version of spontaneous magic?

I haven't thought deeply about it, I would love to read about it if someone has, if someone tried and failed or succeeded, and the exact mechanics involved.

Comment: As it stands, this question is almost certain to be closed as either "too broad" or "primarily opinion based".  If you can edit it into something that fits this Q&A format better, however, it might be a good question .  Hint: be specific.

Comment: Are you aware of the psyfire rules found in [spacemaster companion 2](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/93607/Spacemaster-Companion-2) which are very close to Ars Magica spontaneous magic system?

Comment: @Sardathrion I'm not! I'll try to find a general explanation about it to see if it fits :)

Comment: @JoePerkins Still pretty broad.  I see at least three questions (scaling costs, applying spontaneous realms, and formulatic spells), and this format works better with single questions.  Would also help to indicate what you've already done or tried to do, and how/if that worked for you.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Well, the question is about a whole magic system, I just added some details I particularly wonder about. I'll try to expand the question as I do some more research. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I did something similar to this for Rolemaster based on the idea of a pre-arcane primal magic system, I'll dig up my notes.